# Gradient clipping error in Tensorflow v1.14

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am using gradient clipping during training using the following piece of code

```py
variables = tf.trainable_variables()
enc_vars = [v for v in variables if v.name.startswith('encoder')]

enc_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
gvs = enc_opt.compute_gradients(loss, var_list=enc_vars)
capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -10., 10.), var) for grad, var in gvs]
train_enc = enc_opt.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)
```

I have checked that `enc_vars`, `gvs` are both not empty. But I get error in the sixth line in the above piece of code saying

`ValueError: None values not supported.`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the grad values in your gvs list should be `None`. Cross check it once more. You might find it.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did find a `None` value in one of the gradients